# How to return a Ukrainian Railways ticket?

Tags: trains, refunds, ukraine

I've bought a Ukrainian railways ticket at the train station with my credit card. How can I return it? (the date of travel is in a few days)

Comment: May I ask where you bought the train ticket?

Comment: Central train station in Kiev.

Comment: The section on returns on their website is only available in Ukrainian: [Повернення проїзних документів](http://uz.gov.ua/passengers/povernennya_proyznih_dokumentiv/). In particular, it mentions that you can return tickets at any point of sale, not just the one where you purchased it. If you return before 24 hours pf the departure, you should only be short of service fee.

Comment: Right. You would need to return it at the station. Money will be back at your card in couple of weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research (luckily I speak Russian) and returned my own ticket, so here's how it works.

1. If you bought a ticket **online**, cancelling is simple. Login to the [User Control Panel](http://booking.uz.gov.ua/en/authorization/) and go to the Ticket Return tab:

   [image]

   Enter the details of your electronic ticket and you should receive a refund within 2 weeks. Many people [report](http://notestraveler.info/bilety/kak-sdat-zhd-bilety-onlayn-v-ukraine.html) getting their money within a single day, so it probably depends on your bank.
2. If you bought a ticket at a train station using **cash**, you need to go to a ticket office again for a refund. You don't have to visit the same ticket office, any Ukrainian Railways office can do it. At the Kiev Main Train Station there are separate windows for ticket returns ("повернення квитков").

   To process the return you need your ID (ideally a passport) and the ticket itself. You fill out a short form and get your money back in cash.
3. If you bought a physical ticket using a **credit card**, it gets more complicated. Officially you're supposed to get your money back to the same card, however they're currently unable to process returns to foreign banks. Therefore I received my money back in cash, which was a pleasant surprise.

   Again, bring your ID, fill out several forms, and get your money back.

When doing a return be aware of the following:

1. Returns processed more than **24 hours** before departure only cost a small fee (around 2$). Returns processed later on carry a significant fee, so it's best to do it a day in advance. Returns after the departure of the train are impossible.
2. The ticket office employees speak **zero** English. Therefore I strongly recommend getting a ticket online in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

1. If you have real paper ticket on official blank, there are special ticket windows in any railway station for returning. There you can be served without queue.
2. But better to buy ticket online on booking.uz.gov.ua (official site). Then you can return your ticket in 1 click. And also it is even not required to print ticket, just show bar code in your smartphone :)